# Extract Product, number and quantity from a text file

Tags: command-line, grep

I have improper text file which has product name, website location and quantity. Now I just want to prepare product name, number (extract from URL) and quantity.

Input file:

```
rawfile.txt

Component name  Link    Quantity
Ba Test Con - Red   https://kr.element14.com/multicomp/a-1-126-n-r/banana-plug-16a-4mm-cable-red/dp/1698969 25
Ban Te Con - Black  https://kr.element14.com/multicomp/a-1-126-n-b/plug-16a-4mm-cable-black/dp/1698970  25
Ban Te Con - Black  https://kr.element14.com/hirschmann-testmeasurement/930103700/socket-4mm-black-5pk-mls/dp/1854599   15
```

Expected output:

```
Ba Test Con - Red   1698969 25
Ban Te Con - Black  1698970 25
Ban Te Con - Black  1854599 15
```

My code:

```
For product name:
# extract product name
grep '.*?(?=https://)' rawfile.txt

# extract product number
grep -Po '\b[0-9]{6,7}\t\b' rawfile.txt

# extract quanity
grep -Po '\t[0-9]{1,3}' rawfile.txt

# Now combining the last two functions into one ; this works
# grep -Po '(number argument)(quantity argument)' rawfile.txt
grep -Po '(\b[0-9]{6,7}\t\b)(\t[0-9]{1,3})' rawfile.txt
1698969 25
1698970 25
1854599 15
# Now combining the three functions into one and producing an output text file; this works
# grep -Po '(product name argument)(number argument)(quantity argument)' rawfile.txt
grep -Po '(.*?(?=https://))(\b[0-9]{6,7}\t\b)(\t[0-9]{1,3})' rawfile.txt
```

Present output:

```
>> grep -Po '(.*?(?=https://))(\b[0-9]{6,7}\t\b)(\t[0-9]{1,3})' rawfile.txt
>>                      # no output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like this would do? (can be improved, but you got the idea)

```
$ cat test.txt 
Ba Test Con - Red   https://kr.element14.com/multicomp/a-1-126-n-r/banana-plug-16a-4mm-cable-red/dp/1698969 25
Ban Te Con - Black  https://kr.element14.com/multicomp/a-1-126-n-b/plug-16a-4mm-cable-black/dp/1698970  25
Ban Te Con - Black  https://kr.element14.com/hirschmann-testmeasurement/930103700/socket-4mm-black-5pk-mls/dp/1854599   15

$ sed 's#https://.*/##' test.txt 
Ba Test Con - Red   1698969 25
Ban Te Con - Black  1698970  25
Ban Te Con - Black  1854599   15
```

Comment: Can you please explain the significance of each character in `'s#https://.*/##'` I am surprised that it is so simple.

Comment: The pattern is `s#<chain to replace>#<chain to overwrite it with>#`. `s` is for substitution (I guess), `#` is a delimiter character (you can use another one), `.*` means whatever chain of character(s) (regular expression). So I ask to substitute `https://<whatever chain of characters>/` by nothing (the empty chain). I am essentially asking for the *deletion* of something, whereas your first idea was the *selection* of something.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now it is better. This is okay. Where did you specify to to replace `https://......../` until the last `/` but do not remove the number present after this character? I mean, there are many `/` characters in the string. How come it stop at very end? Thanks

Comment: @Mainland Very good question: in `.*`, the point `.` represents any character, and `*` means that this "any character" is "repeated from 0 to an infinite number of time". By default, this `*` operator is **greedy**: it will "eat" as many characters as possible, and only stop when it really cannot go further. Because I wrote `.*/`, it stopped at the last `/`. In *some* ([non standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09)) implementations, there exists a non greedy (lazy) way of matching: using `.*?`, which would have stopped at the first opportunity.

Comment: Really nice explanation. You don't know how easier it became for me, a beginner. You are a good teacher. Thanks a ton. I just started using `?` to denote ending but your explanation makes a good sense to me what I have been doing. Also, the meaning for each `.`, `*` is really good.

Comment: I have one more question. Your solution is simply perfect and simple. I am wondering why my solution did not work? If you see my solution, I followed steps `grep -Po (first argument)(..)(third argument) rawfile.txt`. It works perfectly correct when I execute it without first argument.

Comment: Thank you. If you match with `grep` even with the `-o` option, you will still need to match a *contiguous* part of line, I'm pretty sure. Asking grep to display something at the beginning and something at the end of a line, without also displaying what's in between is probably not implemented in this tool. Also I could not make some of your working examples on my machine maybe due to missing <tab> characters in the `rawfile.txt` from your question I guess.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it.